# How to prevent ICE CYBER virus - Avira has allowed reinfection

Tags: windows, virus, anti-virus, malware, trojan

The ICE CYBER virus is particularly nasty.  I thought it snuck in while Avira Free Antivir was off, and then became active later.  Being more carefull for the two days after removing it with a Kaspersky rescue disk, I have it again.

It's time for new antivirus software.  What will prevent infection from the ICE CYBER virus?

I tried AVG a while back:  I uninstalled it because it required that all internet traffic be diverted through it's program, and I don't want some AVG person to be able to log all of my internet traffic.    (It would not run without internet access.  I didn't allow AVG with my firewall.  Upon specifically allowing AVG, I got inernet access back.  Goodbye, AVG.)

How I removed the ICE CYBER virus.  I made a Kaspersky rescue disk, and did a scan.  It restored access to my computer.  I then restored XP back to a restore point a couple weeks old with rstrui.exe.  I then ran Kaspersky again, plus Malwarebytes, plus Hitman pro, plus an Antivir full scan.  Two days later I have it again.  Avira Free Antivir failed to prevent the virus.  I had it set for web protection, plus all file reads and writes.

Comment: We do not do product recomendations here at Superuser.  The combination of a paid license of Malwarebytes and MSE has never failed me.  You should figure out the reason you are being infected by malcious files, a browsing habits, should prevent major infections.

Comment: Thanks.  I read "How do I get rid.."   This is how to PREVENT.  Also, that's a general routine, not about a specific virus.

Comment: Yeah, I might finally have to pay for something, and ditch free anti-virus programs.  Browsing habits?  For the last two days I've been doing nothing but researching online graduate schools.

Comment: @user199340 - Do you make sure ALL your software is updated at least once a week?  Do you disable javascript unless you require it through extensions?  Do you block ads unless you approve them?  Do install all system updates when they are released?  Do you avoid using IE8 because of the security concerns?  You can spend no money and if you have good browsing habits you won't be infected by malicous files.  The fact you are being infected with major infections like `Ice Cyber` means you need to look at your browsing habits as the source of the infection.